# generic set to access fields in a Java object via SSJS

Tags: java, xpages, xpages-ssjs

Is there a way to access in a more flexible way fields on a Java object via SSJS?

So when my Java object is stored in a obj variable I can access the created field via obj.created.

However I would make my solution a bit more flexible so the name of the field will be provided via a property definition on a custom control.

The name of the field I get via:

```
compositeData.fieldName
```

How can I bend this to:

```
var field = compositeData.fieldName;
obj.????
```

I tried

```
obj.getField(field);
```

(source: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/class_getfield.htm)

gives me an error:

com.ibm.xsp.binding.javascript.JavaScriptValueBinding.getValue(JavaScriptValueBinding.java:132)

Is there someone with a suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to access object properties by bracket notation:

`obj.fieldName`

is the same as

`obj[compositeData.fieldName]`

You may also want to look at java reflection which may allow you to do:

`obj.get(compositeData.fieldName)`

Comment: Hello Rob, you make development look easy. It works like a charm. Thank you for helping me out!

Comment: No problem Malin.  Happy to help.

Comment: Just bear in mind Java reflection is prevented by the default Java policy. I needed a couple of changes for Watson Workspace Java SDK, see here https://openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/Watson%20Work%20Services%20Java%20SDK/releases/54958F6AB453BEEF852581170033626B. Another option is making your Java class extend the Map interface, as shown by Tim Tripcony in his NotesIn9 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6xUEceG7wlM. (That code gets a lot easier with ODA, Tim had to add a lot of ODA code into his classes)